# Call a Stored Procedure with a DetachedCriteria?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, stored-procedures, criteria-api, detachedcriteria

Is it possible to construct a DetachedCriteria in nHibernate which queries a stored procedure?  How would I accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 3):

I have not done it but you can use some alternatives:

- [Named Queries and SQL Queries](http://ayende.com/blog/3948/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-query-and-sql-query)
- Map to a view instead.
- Map to a TableValued Function (yes this I know this isn't great but it's got me out of a few jams)

Comment: If you want to create a named query in code, [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409812/how-can-the-namedsqlquerydefinition-class-be-used-dynamically-as-a-sql-query-equi) shows how to create it at runtime without HBM files.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

You have to use a SQLQuery to call a stored procedure.

Comment: If that's the case, can you somehow pass a SQLQuery into a Subqueries.PropertyIn() construct?