# How to change this statement to detached criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, detachedcriteria

This statement is to check if the user is existing in the database.

```
public boolean isExisting(int userId) {
    String sql = "{call isExistingUser(?)}";
    Session session = null;
    boolean isExisting = false;
    try {
        session = getSession();
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter(0, userId);
        List<?> list = query.list();
        isExisting = list.get(0) != null ? (Boolean) list.get(0) : false;  
    } finally {
        if (session != null)
            session.close();
    }
    return isExisting;
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

CREATE DEFINER=`cbsadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `isExistingUser`(IN userId int)
BEGIN
    SELECT USER_ID FROM  USER_LOGIN_STATUS WHERE USER_ID = userId;
END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to query a Stored procedure using detached criteria in NHibernate.

You need to use SQL query only.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611124/call-a-stored-procedure-with-a-detachedcriteria).